# Realizar chamada à método em Java

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, método

Estou fazendo alguns exercícios de POO e não consigo chamar o método `ligar` do meu código.

```
    public class Telefone {
    public String modelo;
    public int numeros;
    public boolean antena;

    void status(){
        System.out.println("O modelo do telefone é: " + this.getModelo());
        System.out.println("O telefone possui " + this.getNumeros() + "Numeros");
        System.out.println("A antela dele está pronta? " + this.getAntena());
        System.out.println("O telefone pode ligar?" + this.ligar());
    }

    public String getModelo(){
        return this.modelo;
    }
    public void setModelo(String Modelo){
        modelo = Modelo;
    }

    public int getNumeros(){
        return this.numeros;
    }
    public void setNumeros(int Numeros){
        numeros = Numeros;
    }

    public boolean getAntena(){
        return this.antena;
    }
    public void setAntena(boolean Antena){
        antena = Antena;
    }
    void ligar(){
        if(this.antena == true){
            System.out.println("Estou ligando!");
        } else if (this.antena == false){
            System.out.println("Não posso ligar!");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Ponha public no método ligar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você estava tentando [concatenar](https://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/concatenar-string/565886) com uma `String` a chamada de um método do tipo `void`, ou seja, que não retorna nenhum valor, da seguinte forma: `System.out.println("O telefone pode ligar?" + this.ligar());`. Se sua intenção é saber se é possível realizar ou não a ligação, faça a seguinte alteração no seu código, adicionando na próxima linha a chamada do método `void`, para obter o resultado desejado em seu código:

```
void status(){
    System.out.println("O modelo do telefone é: " + this.getModelo());
    System.out.println("O telefone possui " + this.getNumeros() + " Numeros");
    System.out.println("A antela dele está pronta? " + this.getAntena());
    System.out.println("O telefone pode ligar?");
    this.ligar();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Existem alguns problemas neste código mas vou focar na pergunta. Este método `ligar()` não tem função real aí e não deveria existir, tudo pode ser simplificado:

```
void status(){
    System.out.println("O modelo do telefone é: " + getModelo());
    System.out.println("O telefone possui " + getNumeros() + " Numeros");
    System.out.println("A antela dele está pronta? " + getAntena());
    System.out.println("O telefone pode ligar? " + (antena ? "Estou ligando!" : "Não posso ligar!"));
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/String/ConcatenateConditional.java).

Resolva a causa raiz do problema em vez de procurar alternativas para contornar o problema original criado.

Pense se não dá para eliminar esta última pergunta e já fazer a afirmação, ou simplificar a resposta, parece um texto redundante.

Answer (score 2):

No caso o método ligar() é do tipo void, logo não tem retorno, mas você o chama no println como se retornasse algo. Deveria apenas chama-lo:

```
void status(){
System.out.println("O modelo do telefone é: " + this.getModelo());
System.out.println("O telefone possui " + this.getNumeros() + "Numeros");
System.out.println("A antela dele está pronta? " + this.getAntena());
this.ligar();
}

void ligar(){
if(this.antena == true){
    System.out.println("Estou ligando!");
} else if (this.antena == false){
    System.out.println("Não posso ligar!");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro isto está dentro de uma classe certo? Vamos supor que está classe é

```
public class Telefone{}
```

Após ter definido os metodos dessa classe, você devera instanciar ela na sua classe main ou seu metodo main na sua propria classe como no exemplo abaixo se for um metodo:

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    Telefone telefone = new Telefone(); // Passando os parametros da sua classe dentro dos parenteses.
    telefone.ligar(); // após isso é so utilizar os metodos que você deseja, chamando a classe e logo em seguida o seu metodo.

}
```

Ou caso deseje utilzar esse metodo dentro de alguma das suas funções apenas chame `this.ligar();` onde quiser utiliza-lo.